# Error in getting fitted values

Tags: r

I am having problems getting the fitted values from a linear mixed model (`lmer()`). Normally I would use `fitted()` but I am getting this error:

> Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Is there another way to get the fitted values, or can anyone explain my why I am getting that error?

I am using R version 3.0.1.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you load the `lme4` package?

Comment: Yes. However, getting this: Attaching package: ‘lme4’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    AIC, BIC

Comment: @PJensen That message is expected; don't worry about it. lme4 provides extended functionality for some of the base R functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the `fitted` function from the `lme4` packgage directly with the command

```
lme4::fitted(yourModel)
```